# File download with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, web-applications, download

I'm trying to download an apk file from my webapp using a tablet.

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" id="loginButton" class="pulsantino">Login</a>

$("#pulsanteLogin").live("click",function(){
     alert("1");
     window.location.href = 'http://xx.yy.zz.www:1234/staticResources/Myapp_version.apk';
     alert("2");
}
```

I know for sure that the url is correct (launching it from the browser will correctly start file download), but when i click on the button i get no error and no file download. I get both the alerts for '1' and '2'.

I've tried also with

```
location.href = 'url';
```

and

```
window.location = 'url';
```

Ideas?

Comment: obviously 'url' is the url and not the string 'url'

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too obvious, but why dont you just use a regular link like this directly:

```
<a href="http://xx.yy.zz.www:1234/staticResources/Myapp_version.apk" data-role="button" id="loginButton" class="pulsantino">Login</a>
```

Are you executing more code which requires the dynamic change of this link's `href` attribute?

Comment: What might that logic be? Is that related to this very issue? If it is, you should post that as well and I'll be able to form a better answer.

Comment: i don't think the logic is related to the issue, it's just a check to the Android version

Comment: In that case, my answer would be a solution to your 'problem'; you don't need javascript to handle this click event.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a newer version of jQuery than 1.7? .live() got deprecated, and .on() is now the way to go. http://api.jquery.com/on/

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().
>   Source: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as I said I get both alerts so the problem is not the click event

Comment: Also, couldn't you just do 
`$("#pulsanteLogin").click(function(){
    window.location.href = 'http://xx.yy.zz.www:1234/staticResources/Myapp_version.apk';`
});

Comment: tried, still not working, don't get any error but file isn't downloading